# Integrating GoDaddy DNS with CNAMES and redirects with an Azure website

Tags: domain-name-system, godaddy, azure

I've seen questions similar to this but haven't been able to come up with a solution to my problem yet.

I've been trying to get a site setup with GoDaddy for DNS and windows azure for hosting.

I can't get browsers to pull up `midwestcointrader.com`

They will work fine with both `midwestcointrader.azurewebsites.net` and `www.midwestcointrader.com`

Here's what I have configured now.

```
midwestcointrader.com redirects to www.midwestcointrader.com
www.midwestcointrader.com is a CNAME for midwestcointrader.azurewebsites.net
A record for midwestcointrader.com points to 168.62.20.37
```

Any ideas what I'm missing in the setup process, or information I can include that would be helpful?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A quick look at dig for your zones doesn't show anything glaringly wrong with your DNS configuration, which leads me to believe that this is a web server configuration issue.

If I had to guess, I'd say that you have a binding in IIS for the site in question that will only serve pages if the request comes to `www.midwestcointrader.com`. You should add `midwestcointrader.com` to the site binding as well. I'm not sure how to do this in Azure, but I'm sure it's covered in their documentation.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion! I'll look into the binding issues.

Comment: Did you have any success with this? I am having a similar issue with a Fasthosts domain.